# re-binding a widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox, bind

I want my Listbox "listbox1" to change its binding when the button "button1" is pressed. The first click on the button "disables" the listbox without losing the focus on the selected element in the listbox via `listbox1.bindtags((listbox1, Listbox, ".", "all"))`.

The second click should rebind the listbox with the `<<ListboxSelect>>` binding.

**Q:** How do I rebind the listbox? I tried to do a simple `listbox1.configure`, `listbox1.bind`, reversing the arguments in `listbox1.bindtags`, googled, looked here and i still can't figure it out.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

buttontext = StringVar()
buttontext.set("Disable")
frame_1 = Frame(root, bg="white")
frame_1.pack()

def print_(event):
    print("success")

listbox_1 = Listbox(frame_1, activestyle="none", selectmode=SINGLE, height=6, width=11)
listbox_1.pack()
listbox_1.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", print_)  
listbox_1.insert(0, "test1")
listbox_1.insert(1, "test2")

def toggle_button():      
    if buttontext.get() == "Disable": 
        listbox_1.bindtags((listbox_1, Listbox, ".", "all"))
        listbox_1["exportselection"] = False
        buttontext.set("Normal")

    elif buttontext.get() == "Normal":
        listbox_1.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", print_) 
        listbox_1["exportselection"] = True
        buttontext.set("Disable")

button = Button(frame_1, textvariable=buttontext, command=toggle_button)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: this code won't run, it has a remarkable number of errors. `buttntxt` isn't defined, `do_smth` isn't defined, there is a syntax error on line 18, `buttntxt.get()` isn't a valid statement, you can't supply a class as a bindtag, ...

Comment: its not really about the surroundings, i know that THIS code won't run, but my acutal code does. my question is only how to re-bind a widget. btw buttntxt and buttontxt is the same variable, it is a speeling mistake

Comment: To rebind a widget, you simply call the `bind` method. Since you claim you've tried that and it didn't work, we need to see what you _actually_ tried, not some pretend code.

Comment: the original code is 481 lines long, i dont know if that would be too confusing. :( basically what i am doing is telling "listbox1.bindtags((listbox1, Listbox, ".", "all"))" in the if clause, and in the elif clause it is "listbox1.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", function1)"

Comment: @tumper then please check the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), more specifically the section on writing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I edited, shortened and simplified the code above (in my initial question) down to the core problem. If the button is pressed to disable the listbox it works fine, but if you press the button again it does not re-bind the listbox with the <<ListboxSelect>>. How do I do that?

Comment: We don't need the original code, we need a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

The problem starts with this line of code:

```
listbox_1.bindtags((listbox_1, Listbox, ".", "all"))
```

It is not doing what you think it is doing. While it does in effect disable the widget, it's because you are replacing a valid tag with an invalid tag. If you want to disable the widget by removing or changing the default tags, the more correct way is to simply remove the default bind tag:

```
listbox_1.bindtags((listbox_1, ".", "all"))
```

To restore the bindings all you have to do is restore the bind tags. Notice how I'm using `"Listbox"` as a string, not the actual class:

```
listbox_1.bindtags((listbox_1, "Listbox", ".", "all")
```

Note: you do *not* need to re-add the binding, you only need to re-establish the proper bind tags:

```
def toggle_button():      
    if buttontext.get() == "Disable": 
        listbox_1.bindtags((listbox_1, ".", "all"))
        buttontext.set("Normal")

    elif buttontext.get() == "Normal":
        listbox_1.bindtags((listbox_1, "Listbox", ".", "all"))
        buttontext.set("Disable")
```

Comment: Ah okay now I understand. So instead of replacing the binding it is better to remove it and later restore it, got it. It works just fine, that was big help. Thank you!

Comment: You can replace the bind tag if you want, but if you replace it with something useless then you might as well just remove it. When you change the bind tag to something that makes no sense, the implication is that you did it for a reason. However, replacing the bind tag with `Listbox` served no purpose, making the code harder to understand.